# Getting friends with facebook API PHP SDK v5.1

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-friends

I need get all friends of logged user (only id, name, and picture).

```
/* Facebook API */
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'                => FB_APP_ID,
    'app_secret'            => FB_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => FB_DEFAULT_VERSION
    ]);
$accessToken = $_SESSION['fb_access_token'];

$response = $fb->get('/me/friends', $accessToken);
$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
print_r($graphEdge);die;
```

But returns always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was put user_friends on permissions in Facebook Login

```
$permissions = ['email', 'user_friends'];
$loginFbUrl  = $helper->getLoginUrl($serverUrl, $permissions);
```

Comment: you know, that is in my answer already...(user_friends permission), and there is NO way to get ALL friends.

Answer (score 2):

You can´t get all friends anymore, you can only get friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too. The answer in this thread (and countless others) will tell you more: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)